# Different constant values for junit

Tags: java

There are few constants defined in my class under test and there is some part of logic that depends on value of these constants.

In my case, I create multiple batches from a input CSV file. Size of each batch is defined in a constant. I am creating a small input file and passing it to test case. But since file is very small, It creates only one batch.

One obvious solution is to create a bigger file and pass it to test case. But I would have to create a really big file like 15MB. Other approach is, If I can tweak constants to have smaller values in test cases, which will certainly require a hacky approach.

I sense that first solution is correct one, but any suggestions?

Comment: To answer how it exactly should be done more info is needed, but generally - using reflection API allows you to 'hack' and change these constants. Though it is extremely dangerous, and should usually be avoided, it is sometimes OK to use it in unit-testing.

Comment: Also, you could always create a garbage 15MB file programmatically, it will probably test your component better.

Comment: This is also an option. Except I would have to write lot of mock behavior of so many batches created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could change the constant via reflection but the fact that you need to change it suggests that you should probably reconsider the design of your class.

How about passing the size of each batch to your class' constructor?

- It makes your class more flexible for actual use (you might decide at some stage that the size should increase/decrease or use different sizes for different use cases)
- Your class would be testable again

Comment: There is an upper limit to this size. So I was wondering if I should throw exception if client limit exceeds or reset it to max limit. Probably resetting to max limit and mentioning in javadoc about this behavior is more logical.

Comment: @Jitendra Yes - document in javadoc what are the allowed values and throw an IllegalArgumentException if something else is passed by the client.